# Sort Content in drupal 6 views using date and time seperate fields

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

I've two separate fields of date and time and i added these fields in the sorting portion of the view. When i see results, results are different as i expect. example is given below.

contents having these values regarding date and time i get this result in the same manner...

```
12-jan-2012 and time 2:00pm
12-jan-2012 and time 3:00pm
13-jan-2012 and time 1:00pm
12-feb-2012 and time 2:00am
12-march-2012 and time 2:00pm
```

I want to sort by date and time and results should be

```
12-jan-2012 and time 1:00pm
12-jan-2012 and time 2:00pm
13-jan-2012 and time 3:00pm
12-feb-2012 and time 2:00am
12-march-2012 and time 2:00pm
```

Please suggest how can i handle this situation in the drupal views.

thanks in advance....

Comment: You have different rows in your listings. As in different content, not just different order. It is really hard to grasp what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

In Sort criteria section, add "Node: post date" field and then choose Ascending radio button.

You will get the ascending result or you can use "table" style and choose asc.